# Flutter: How to dynamically add a new textfield based on user selection?

Tags: android, flutter, api, mobile

So I want to add a new textfield after i select an option but since I'm new to flutter I can't figure it out on how to do it .

```
SelectFieldBloc selectFieldBloc = SelectFieldBloc(
                name: question.name,
                toJson: (option) => option?.optionText,
                validators: question.validation != null
                    ? [
                        (input) {
                          if (input != null) {
                            if (input is Option) {
                              Option option = input;
                              return inspectionValidator.inspect(
                                  option.optionText, question.validation);
                            } else if (input is SubOption) {
                              SubOption option = input;
                              return inspectionValidator.inspect(
                                  option.optionText, question.validation);
                            }
                          } else {
                            return inspectionValidator.inspect(
                                input, question.validation);
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    : null,
                items: question.option);
            fieldBloc = selectFieldBloc;
            List<Widget> widgets = [];
            fieldBloc.onValueChanges(onData: (previous, current) async* {
              print(current.value?.optionText);
              if (current.value?.optionText == "Cultivated") {
                widgets.add(
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Enter your username',
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            });
          }
          addFieldBloc(
            step: question.formId! - 1,
            fieldBloc: fieldBloc,
          );
```

I've tried to add a widget.add textfield  but I don't know where it went wrong.The following shows what I've done.

```
 fieldBloc = selectFieldBloc;
            List<Widget> widgets = [];
            fieldBloc.onValueChanges(onData: (previous, current) async* {
              print(current.value?.optionText);
              if (current.value?.optionText == "Cultivated") {
                widgets.add(
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Enter your username',
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look I don't understand what exactly want to do, but If you want to add widget to list of widget you can simply create list and pass it into column or listview, when you add new widget re-render the UI using setState or one of the design patterns , also there is a widget call AnimtedList on flutter you can add or remove widget inside it ,
AnimatedList
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html

And there is an example for adding widget into list of widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Widget> widgets = [];
  Widget _createFormField(
      {required TextEditingController controller, required String hint}) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: _inputDecoration(hint),
      ),
    );
  }

  int index = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
      height: 50,
      width: 100,
      child: CupertinoButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        color: Colors.purple.shade300,
        onPressed: () {
          widgets.add(
            _createFormField(
                controller: TextEditingController(),
                hint: "field ${index++}"),
          );
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: Text('Add field'),
      ),
    ),
   
        body: Visibility(
          visible: widgets.isNotEmpty,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: widgets.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => widgets[index]),
          replacement: Center(child: Text('no items')),
        ));
  }

  InputBorder _border() => OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 1,
            color: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(.7),
            style: BorderStyle.solid),
      );
  InputDecoration _inputDecoration(String hint) => InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
        filled: true,
        enabledBorder: _border(),
        focusedBorder: _border(),
        border: _border(),
        disabledBorder: _border(),
        errorBorder: _border(),
        focusedErrorBorder: _border(),
        errorStyle: const TextStyle(color: Color(0xffff99c2)),
        fillColor: Color(0xffff99c2),
        hintText: hint,
        alignLabelWithHint: true,
      );
}
```

[image]